# how can i define the ctx in this, im trying to make a discord bot that predicts a sites roulette spin for me

Tags: python, web-scraping, request, discord.py

i have read many stack overflow threads and none of them helped me, also this was a / command project but i'm trying to convert it to a simple prefix command
**edit:** i fixed the original problem and as the site i tried to scrape didn't answer the first time it was asked to, so i made this while loop to it so it would scrape it until it would get the answer, but it prints this always "Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)" and i dont know how to fix this or what the problem is

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def roulette(ctx: any):
    roulette = False
    while roulette == False:
        try:
            # bloxflip = scraper.get('http://api.bloxflip.com/games/roulette').json()
            bloxflip = requests.get('https://api.bloxflip.com/games/roulette')
            bloxflip.json()
            roulette = True
        except requests.exceptions.JSONDecodeError as e:
            print(e)
```

i hope that someone would understand and could help me with this

Comment: What are you trying to do? Any errors?

Comment: im sorry i forgot to edit this when i found out that it was not the actual problem

Answer (score 0):

I did not understand clearly what do u need but if u want to know what is the ctx
it is commmands.Context

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def roulette(ctx: discord.ext.commands.Context):
```